# JSON not returning any output while parsing

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I am not much experienced in JSON, so the question might be a little trivial, but I can not sort this out.
I have a simple JSON string like:

```
["{\"__type:\"GeoPoint\",\"latitude\":51.165691,\"longitude\":10.451526}","{\"__type:\"GeoPoint\",\"latitude\":20.593684,\"longitude\":78.96288}"]
```

I want to parse the JSON and get the values in different variables. I have implemented the below code snippet but it is not working as expected. I can see no log after parsing the JSON. **The code:**

```
String jsonString = arg0.get(i).get(0).getJSONArray("tripPoints").toString();
                                Log.e("Json String", jsonString);
                                 JSONArray jsonarray;
                                try {
                                    jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
                                    for(int j=0; j<jsonarray.length(); j++){
                                        JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(j);

                                        String latitude = obj.getString("latitude");
                                        String longitude = obj.getString("longitude");

                                        Log.e("triplatitude", latitude);
                                        Log.e("triplongitude", longitude);
                                    }   
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
```

**What should I do to get the data from the JSON? Where am I going wrong?**

Comment: What does the log Log.e("Json String", jsonString); say in the logcat? What exception is throwed in de logcat?

Comment: @DanielMartinus Log.e("Json String", jsonString); just logs the JSON string that is posted on the question in the top. It does not throw any exception, the  Log.e("triplatitude", latitude);
                                        Log.e("triplongitude", longitude); does not show up in the logcat

Comment: you are trying to get string from latitude and longitude while infact they are not strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON array does not contain valid JSON objects. Removing the `\` escape characters, you end up with this, which is not valid JSON:

```
[
    "{"__type:"GeoPoint","latitude":51.165691,"longitude":10.451526}",
    "{"__type:"GeoPoint","latitude":20.593684,"longitude":78.96288}"
]
```

Try fixing the JSON first and then see if this solves your issue. You can use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to make sure the JSON is valid.

Basically your JSON should look something like this:

```
[
    {
        "__type": "GeoPoint",
        "latitude": 51.165691,
        "longitude": 10.451526
    },
    {
        "__type": "GeoPoint",
        "latitude": 20.593684,
        "longitude": 78.96288
    }
]
```

**EDIT 1**

Seems like there's a bit of confusion. The issue is that the following is a string in JSON terms:

```
"{"__type:"GeoPoint","latitude":51.165691,"longitude":10.451526}"
```

We need an object, so we remove the `"` from the start and the end which turns it into the following:

```
{"__type:"GeoPoint","latitude":51.165691,"longitude":10.451526}
```

This is invalid JSON. What we need to do to fix this is add a `"` after `__type`. Now it looks like this:

```
{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":51.165691,"longitude":10.451526}
```

Finally it's valid. You need to find a way to fix the JSON at the source. What is the `arg0` object and where does it get its data?

**EDIT 2**

If you can't fix the JSON at the source the following quick hack should work for this case:

```
jsonString = jsonString.replace("__type", "__type\"")
        .replace("\"{", "{")
        .replace("}\"", "}")
        .replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

Comment: If you can then please post the suggested code about how to make the JSON valid and parse it.

Comment: First, where do you get the JSON from? It will need to be fixed at the source. The code is fine, just not the raw JSON.

Comment: It is generated from parse.com and its valid in the whole project.

Comment: Can you please post the value you get from `arg0.get(i).get(0)`?

Comment: removing .getJSONArray("tripPoints") ?

Comment: @DanielMartinus No, that's what's in `arg0.get(i).get(0).getJSONArray("tripPoints").toString();`. I'm trying to see the raw JSON before it's turned into a JSONArray.

Comment: I returns the json string that is posted on the top of the question.

Comment: @kittu88 Ok, but do you see why the actual JSON is invalid? If not, I suggest reading up more about the structure of JSON.

Comment: I have pasted the JSON in http://jsonlint.com/ and it says its a valid JSON

Comment: So can you suggest a regex or something to do the same? Nothing could be done in Parse database as the output is generated automatically

Comment: @kittu88 see 2nd edit

Comment: after fixing JSON what should be done? How will I parse it?

Comment: new json: [{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":7.873054,"longitude":80.771797},{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":71.706936,"longitude":-42.604303}]

Comment: @kittu88 Add the code in my 2nd edit after the following line: `String jsonString = arg0.get(i).get(0).getJSONArray("tripPoints").toString();`. Then run the code again and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your json (in the json array) without escaping and with a little formatting looks like this:

```
[
 {
      "__type": "GeoPoint",
      "latitude": 51.165691,
      "longitude": 10.451526
  },
  {
      "__type": "GeoPoint",
      "latitude": 20.593684,
      "longitude": 78.96288
  }
]
```

I assume `__type` would work when you comment out latitude and longitude and insert: obj.getString("__type"); But you are now using obj.getString on latitude and longitude while they are not strings.

So use for latitude and longitude: *(Edit: this is not necessary since the json parser will make it automatically a String)*

```
obj.getDouble("latitude");
```

**edit**

I actually just tested your code and this worked:

```
String jsonString = " [{\n" +
            "      \"__type\": \"GeoPoint\",\n" +
            "      \"latitude\": 51.165691,\n" +
            "      \"longitude\": 10.451526\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "      \"__type\": \"GeoPoint\",\n" +
            "      \"latitude\": 20.593684,\n" +
            "      \"longitude\": 78.96288\n" +
            "  }]";

    JSONArray jsonarray;
    try {
        jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        for(int j=0; j<jsonarray.length(); j++){
            JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(j);

            String latitude = obj.getString("latitude");
            String longitude = obj.getString("longitude");

            Log.e("triplatitude", latitude);
            Log.e("triplongitude", longitude);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: No man, that is not showing the __type

Comment: See edit in my answer, only thing i changed is the jsonString. And i used the one from above the edit and used array prefix `[` `]` before the two objects.

Comment: String jsonString = arg0.get(i).get(0).getJSONArray("tripPoints").toString(); contains the JSON. What should I add before or after?

Comment: @kittu88 See my answer, you need to fix the raw JSON from the source.

Comment: @user32116 Thats excactly whats in my answer. @kittu88 you need to add `[` at the begin of the json String and `]` at the end of the json string. If you can't change the json string because its from an API try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27188397/1164919 Since without `[` and `]` it's an JSONObject and not an `JSONArray`. did you try out my code in my answer here above?

Comment: @DanielMartinus I posted the answer before your edit, but anyways. It's not the `[]` that's the problem, it's the `"` characters.

Comment: I have added         String jsonString = "["+arg0.get(i).get(0).getJSONArray("tripPoints").toString()+"]"; the resulting JSON is [["{\"__type:\"GeoPoint\",\"latitude\":51.165691,\"longitude\":10.451526}","{\"__type:\"GeoPoint\",\"latitude\":20.593684,\"longitude\":78.96288}"]] so it had basically added one extra box bracket at the beginning and end.

Comment: Then the json string is correct. Did you already try out my code on the bottom of my answer? I tested it and it should work. Just place it in an onCreate of an activity somewhere to easily test it.

Comment: @DanielMartinus http://jsonlint.com/ calls it a valid json. The previous one without the [] [
    "{\"__type:\"GeoPoint\",\"latitude\":51.165691,\"longitude\":10.451526}",
    "{\"__type:\"GeoPoint\",\"latitude\":20.593684,\"longitude\":78.96288}"
]

Comment: again @kittu88 did you try out my code? that its valid json was already known.

Comment: @kittu88 Please comment on my original answer. You need to remove the `"` before `{` and after `}`. It will then say it's invalid due to the missing `"` after `__type`.

Comment: @DanielMartinus I did try it out, its not showing any result as it did earlier

Comment: @kittu88 sorry but if it ain't showing any results and you got no exception then your logcat is wrong i guess. Do you have it on `verbose`? Already tried debugging with breakpoints and checking the values? Or set a toast. `Toast.makeText(mContext, latitude + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` in the for loop