# Error in parsing json android

Tags: android, json

I am using the following code to parse JSON:

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(str);
        // Getting JSON Array node
        JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
        // looping through All Contacts
        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = c.getString(TAG_MENU_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_MENU_NAME);
            String type = c.getString(TAG_MENU_TYPE);
            String price = c.getString(TAG_MENU_PRICE);
            String url = c.getString(TAG_MENU_IMAGE_URL);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My JSON string is as follows:

```
{"header":{"MessageID":1350338501,"API_Version":"1.0","API_Name":"Get Menu Details","Date":"2015-07-24 10:48:02","Content_Type":"application/json"},"data":{"1":{"MENU_ID":"1","MENU_NAME":"Chapati","MENU_PRICE":"110.00","MENU_TYPE":"VEG","MENU_IMAGE_URL":"http://www.mummystiffin.com/mytiffin/images/MenuImages/menu-2015-07-11-17-21-33_thumb.png","IsActive":"1","ADDED_ON":"2015-06-20 00:00:00","LAST_UPDATED_ON":"2015-07-11 17:21:36","IsSubmited":"1"},"2":{"MENU_ID":"2","MENU_NAME":"Chinken Curry","MENU_PRICE":"120.00","MENU_TYPE":"NON VEG","MENU_IMAGE_URL":"http://www.mummystiffin.com/mytiffin/images/MenuImages/menu-2015-07-11-17-29-54_thumb.png","IsActive":"1","ADDED_ON":"2015-07-11 12:50:52","LAST_UPDATED_ON":"2015-07-11 17:29:59","IsSubmited":"1"},"3":{"MENU_ID":"3","MENU_NAME":"Chole_Pattis","MENU_PRICE":"130.00","MENU_TYPE":"VEG","MENU_IMAGE_URL":"http://www.mummystiffin.com/mytiffin/images/MenuImages/menu-2015-07-11-17-32-16_thumb.png","IsActive":"1","ADDED_ON":"2015-07-11 13:01:21","LAST_UPDATED_ON":"2015-07-11 17:32:21","IsSubmited":"1"},"4":{"MENU_ID":"4","MENU_NAME":"Mexican","MENU_PRICE":"140.00","MENU_TYPE":"VEG","MENU_IMAGE_URL":"http://www.mummystiffin.com/mytiffin/images/MenuImages/menu-2015-07-11-17-32-58_thumb.png","IsActive":"1","ADDED_ON":"2015-07-11 13:01:36","LAST_UPDATED_ON":"2015-07-11 17:33:09","IsSubmited":"1"},"7":{"MENU_ID":"7","MENU_NAME":"Pasta","MENU_PRICE":"150.00","MENU_TYPE":"VEG","MENU_IMAGE_URL":"http://www.mummystiffin.com/mytiffin/images/MenuImages/menu-2015-07-11-18-15-52_thumb.png","IsActive":"1","ADDED_ON":"2015-07-11 17:35:54","LAST_UPDATED_ON":"2015-07-11 18:16:03","IsSubmited":"1"}},"summary":{"count":5,"status":"SUCCESS"}}
```

However, I am getting following error at the line

```
JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
```

This is the exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value 

{"3":{"MENU_NAME":"Chole_Pattis","IsActive":"1","MENU_TYPE":"VEG","IsSubmited":"1","MENU_IMAGE_URL":"http:\/\/www.mummystiffin.com\/mytiffin\/images\/MenuImages\/menu-2015-07-11-17-32-16_thumb.png","MENU_ID":"3","LAST_UPDATED_ON":"2015-07-11 17:32:21","MENU_PRICE":"130.00","ADDED_ON":"2015-07-11 13:01:21"},"2":{"MENU_NAME":"Chinken Curry","IsActive":"1","MENU_TYPE":"NON VEG","IsSubmited":"1","MENU_IMAGE_URL":"http:\/\/www.mummystiffin.com\/mytiffin\/images\/MenuImages\/menu-2015-07-11-17-29-54_thumb.png","MENU_ID":"2","LAST_UPDATED_ON":"2015-07-11 17:29:59","MENU_PRICE":"120.00","ADDED_ON":"2015-07-11 12:50:52"},"1":{"MENU_NAME":"Chapati","IsActive":"1","MENU_TYPE":"VEG","IsSubmited":"1","MENU_IMAGE_URL":"http:\/\/www.mummystiffin.com\/mytiffin\/images\/MenuImages\/menu-2015-07-11-17-21-33_thumb.png","MENU_ID":"1","LAST_UPDATED_ON":"2015-07-11 17:21:36","MENU_PRICE":"110.00","ADDED_ON":"2015-06-20 00:00:00"},"7":{"MENU_NAME":"Pasta","IsActive":"1","MENU_TYPE":"VEG","IsSubmited":"1","MENU_IMAGE_URL":"http:\/\/www.mummystiffin.com\/mytiffin\/images\/MenuImages\/menu-2015-07-11-18-15-52_thumb.png","MENU_ID":"7","LAST_UPDATED_ON":"2015-07-11 18:16:03","MENU_PRICE":"150.00","ADDED_ON":"2015-07-11 17:35:54"},"4":{"MENU_NAME":"Mexican","IsActive":"1","MENU_TYPE":"VEG","IsSubmited":"1","MENU_IMAGE_URL":"http:\/\/www.mummystiffin.com\/mytiffin\/images\/MenuImages\/menu-2015-07-11-17-32-58_thumb.png","MENU_ID":"4","LAST_UPDATED_ON":"2015-07-11 17:33:09","MENU_PRICE":"140.00","ADDED_ON":"2015-07-11 13:01:36"}}

at data of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

I'm not sure why it is giving me this error for the 3rd value, since it is able to parse the first two objects. I have checked the JSON, and it appears to be in the proper format.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can i ask you, what api you are using ? i need to this api codes.thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following json is

```
{
"header": {
    "MessageID": 1350338501,
    "API_Version": "1.0",
    "API_Name": "Get Menu Details",
    "Date": "2015-07-24 10:48:02",
    "Content_Type": "application/json"
},
"data": {
    "1": {
        "MENU_ID": "1",
        "MENU_NAME": "Chapati",
        "MENU_PRICE": "110.00",
        "MENU_TYPE": "VEG",
        "MENU_IMAGE_URL": "http://www.mummystiffin.com/mytiffin/images/MenuImages/menu-2015-07-11-17-21-33_thumb.png",
        "IsActive": "1",
        "ADDED_ON": "2015-06-20 00:00:00",
        "LAST_UPDATED_ON": "2015-07-11 17:21:36",
        "IsSubmited": "1"
    },
    "2": {
        "MENU_ID": "2",
        "MENU_NAME": "Chinken Curry",
        "MENU_PRICE": "120.00",
        "MENU_TYPE": "NON VEG",
        "MENU_IMAGE_URL": "http://www.mummystiffin.com/mytiffin/images/MenuImages/menu-2015-07-11-17-29-54_thumb.png",
        "IsActive": "1",
        "ADDED_ON": "2015-07-11 12:50:52",
        "LAST_UPDATED_ON": "2015-07-11 17:29:59",
        "IsSubmited": "1"
    },
    "3": {
        "MENU_ID": "3",
        "MENU_NAME": "Chole_Pattis",
        "MENU_PRICE": "130.00",
        "MENU_TYPE": "VEG",
        "MENU_IMAGE_URL": "http://www.mummystiffin.com/mytiffin/images/MenuImages/menu-2015-07-11-17-32-16_thumb.png",
        "IsActive": "1",
        "ADDED_ON": "2015-07-11 13:01:21",
        "LAST_UPDATED_ON": "2015-07-11 17:32:21",
        "IsSubmited": "1"
    },
    "4": {
        "MENU_ID": "4",
        "MENU_NAME": "Mexican",
        "MENU_PRICE": "140.00",
        "MENU_TYPE": "VEG",
        "MENU_IMAGE_URL": "http://www.mummystiffin.com/mytiffin/images/MenuImages/menu-2015-07-11-17-32-58_thumb.png",
        "IsActive": "1",
        "ADDED_ON": "2015-07-11 13:01:36",
        "LAST_UPDATED_ON": "2015-07-11 17:33:09",
        "IsSubmited": "1"
    },
    "7": {
        "MENU_ID": "7",
        "MENU_NAME": "Pasta",
        "MENU_PRICE": "150.00",
        "MENU_TYPE": "VEG",
        "MENU_IMAGE_URL": "http://www.mummystiffin.com/mytiffin/images/MenuImages/menu-2015-07-11-18-15-52_thumb.png",
        "IsActive": "1",
        "ADDED_ON": "2015-07-11 17:35:54",
        "LAST_UPDATED_ON": "2015-07-11 18:16:03",
        "IsSubmited": "1"
    }
},
"summary": {
    "count": 5,
    "status": "SUCCESS"
  }
}
```

the object of key "data" is JSONObject not the JSONArray

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(str);
    // Getting JSON Array node
    //JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
    // comment the above line ..and rest is same
    JSONObject contacts = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
    // looping through All Contacts
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
        if(contacts.has(String.valueOf(i))
        {
           JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i));
           String id = c.getString(TAG_MENU_ID);
           String name = c.getString(TAG_MENU_NAME);
           String type = c.getString(TAG_MENU_TYPE);
           String price = c.getString(TAG_MENU_PRICE);
           String url = c.getString(TAG_MENU_IMAGE_URL);
         }
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but data has KEY 1,2,3,4,7 , and you are using String.valueOf(i) which will result 0 which is not there also  value of i will never be 7 ?

Comment: if the key is constant like 1,2,3,4,7 then instead using for loop you have to work manually...or use jsonobject.has("key"); i've updated the ans.. plz check

Comment: check if key "0" exist ..if exist then parse the data ..else increment the loop

Answer (score 1):

Your "data" object is not JSONArray its JSONObject. You are trying to access it as json array. try below function to parse your json

```
    try
    {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONObject contacts = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
        for (int i = 1; i <= contacts.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i));
            String id = c.getString(TAG_MENU_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_MENU_NAME);
            String type = c.getString(TAG_MENU_TYPE);
            String price = c.getString(TAG_MENU_PRICE);
            String url = c.getString(TAG_MENU_IMAGE_URL);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your parsing content "data" is name of array having keys 1,2,3,4,7 you have to parse those keys and fetch these values:
MENU_ID,MENU_NAME etc.

below is an example to get all key values:
[How to parse JSON with any key on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185629/how-to-parse-json-with-any-key-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

The "data" property in the JSON response is not a JSON Array, but a JSON object. The indexes are just property names. You should modify you code to extract the available properties using `JsonObect.keys()` or `JsonObject.names()` and extract the value of each property from the object, then parse it.