# Parse JSON with unknown key?

Tags: java, json

i have a Json output like this :

[image]

The numbers 2922 and 3910 are random numbers.
How can i store all values that are in "name" in an array?

Thank you.

Comment: Refer this solution :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/27188397/3946958

Answer (score 12):

You can use **[Iterator.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)**

> Using Iterator, you can iterate all elements of a list in either
>   direction. You can access next element by calling next() method .

```
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(success);
                Iterator  iteratorObj = reader .keys();
                ArrayList<String> al_getAllKeys=new ArrayList<String>();
                while (iteratorObj.hasNext())
                {
                    String getJsonObj = (String)iteratorObj.next();
                    System.out.println("KEY: " + "------>" + getJsonObj);

                }
```