# How to get json object and array values?

Tags: android, arrays, json

How to parse JSON values in this format? I want to get the details of the data element but inside data there are 'dates' and inside dates there is array containing two more elements. I want to get all the dates first inside data and then within these dates I want all the information within these dates. How can I achieve this? Please Help. **I tried with below code but it hasn't worked**

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("data");
    JSONArray jsonArray =jsonObject.getJSONArray(String.valueof(cuurentdate));

    JSONArray session;
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length() - 1; i++) {
        jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        session= jsonObject.getJSONArray("session");

        Log.d("MyLog", session + "");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Following is the format**

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "status_code": 200,
  "data": {
    "2018-02-11": [
      {
        "session": "01:00 AM",
        "place": true

      },
      {
        "session": "02:00 AM",
        "place": true

      }
    ],
    "2018-02-12": [
      {
        "session": "01:00 AM",
        "place": true

      },
      {
        "session": "02:00 AM",
        "place": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Invalid JSON variable.

Comment: edited, that was a typo mistake

Comment: Your json format is not valid now.

Comment: Can you please help me with correction? I am a newbie to this parsing thing

Comment: Check your json here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: just you need to get 1 session object from date Array right?

Comment: @RaviMakvana yes exactly, all the session objects within date objects

Comment: Your Array is dynamic. so follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/43255611/3395198

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Ok thanks, let me check

Comment: You should first iterating through "data":

Comment: @MilosLulic can you explain a bit more in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass the response string to the method. You can try this:

```
  private void jsonParsing(String jsonString) {

   // String jsonString = "{ \"status\": 1, \"status_code\": 200, \"data\": { \"2018-02-11\": [ { \"session\": \"01:00 AM\", \"place\": true }, { \"session\": \"02:00 AM\", \"place\": true } ], \"2018-02-12\": [ { \"session\": \"01:00 AM\", \"place\": true }, { \"session\": \"02:00 AM\", \"place\": true } ] } }";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONObject dataObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");

        Iterator<String> iter = dataObj.keys();

        Log.e(TAG, "jsonParsing: "+iter );

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String key = iter.next();
                JSONArray datesArray = dataObj.getJSONArray(key);

                ArrayList<String> sessions = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (int i = 0; i < datesArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject datesObject = datesArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    sessions.add(datesObject.getString("session"));
                }
                Log.d("MyLog", sessions + "");

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,. let me check this

Comment: Can you please tell what to write in json string. Is it empty?

Comment: The json that you want to parse.

Comment: Parsing start from data object, there is no string on top of 'status' bracket. Sorry if i am doing something wrong

Comment: when i hit the api, then in return this json response comes which i shared. Curly brackets and then status, status code and then data thing

Comment: Yes now i understand, thankyou, let me check with this

Comment: Works like a charm, Thankyou so much :)

Answer (score 1):

(1) get JSONObject of Main json

```
 JSONObject objMain = new JSONObject("your json string");
```

(2)get JSONObject of "data" from main json

```
 JSONObject jsonData = objMain.getJSONObject("data")
```

(3) get all keys (dates) from object "data"

```
Iterator<String> iter = jsonData.keys();

while (iter.hasNext()) {

 String key = iter.next();

try {
     JSONArray arrayDate = objData.getJSONArray(key)
     for (i = 0; i < arrayDate.length(); i++) {

           JSONObject objDate = arrayDate.getJSONObject(i)
           Log.d("#session :", "" + objDate.getString("session"))
           Log.d("#place :", "" + objDate.getBoolean("place"))
          }
 } catch (JSONException e) {
    // Something went wrong!
  }
}
```

Comment: issue was resolved, thankyou for your help. UPVOTE :)

Answer (score 0):

try this one code

> IN THIS CODE jsonMstObject IS TEMP OBJECT YOU HAVE TO USE YOUR API RESPONSE JSONobject INSTEAD OF jsonMstObject

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonMstObject = new JSONObject("{"status":1,"status_code":200,"data":{"2018-02-11":[{"session":"01:00 AM","place":true},{"session":"02:00 AM","place":true}],"2018-02-12":[{"session":"01:00 AM","place":true},{"session":"02:00 AM","place":true}]}}");

        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonMstObject.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray jsonArray =jsonObject.getJSONArray(String.valueof(cuurentdate));

        ArrayList<String> arrSession = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            arrSession.add(jsonObject.getString("session"));
        }

        Log.d("MyLog", arrSession + "");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

in this code arrSession is your session string array

Ex. you passed cuurentdate = "2018-02-11" then you recived result like

> [01:00 AM, 02:00 AM]

Note: this code is worked based on your **cuurentdate** param. This is code for get static date array from data and create String Array.

Comment: Thanks, let me check this

Comment: JSON Exception - value data of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonobject

Comment: @Arslan Ali ok got it use JSONObject jsonObject = jsonMstObject.getJSONObject("data"); instered of  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("data");

Comment: in this jsonMstObject is your Response JSONObject