# How to update a JSON array in a Java

Tags: java, android, json, spring, spring-boot

I have a JSON file name abc.json
Once I opened this file there is data like in square brackets.

```
[{
"1" : "xxx",
"20" : "ppp",
"25" : "hhh"
}]
```

Here in this keys are not known. I want to add new key-value pairs, update values according to some key-value and delete some fields.
I have to use `com.google.code`  library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255577/parse-json-with-unknown-key/43255611#43255611

Comment: That's great... Also can you tell me how to add new field in same JSON file which should maintain square brackets as opening and closing? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to update the JSON file? This is a non-standard use of JSON. If you are storing data, you should consider using a database, such as SQLite or Realm, instead of a JSON file.

Comment: Also note that if this JSON file is stored in `res` or `asset` in your Android Studio package, you cannot update it anyway. (At least not easily)

Comment: That's the correct point by @Code-Apprentice. But as it was asked by one of my friend whose organization given a task like this. They are using Java to build API. Could you please provide any way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are building an API, you don't need to save the a JSON file. Typically you build up an object then serialize it to JSON directly to the HTTP response. Any modifications should be made to the Java objects before serializing them.

Answer (score 0):

As said already in comments, there are some flaws in this architecture.

However, as a json object is basically a Map in java, you can use `jackson` lib to deserialize the json, add a value in the map and serialize it again with `jackson`. See the code below :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


class ObjectMapperTest {


    @Test
    void test_json_array_of_map() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String jsonAsString = "[{\"1\":\"xxx\",\"20\":\"ppp\",\"25\":\"hhh\"}]";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<Map<String,String>> deserialized = objectMapper.readValue(jsonAsString, new TypeReference<>() {
        });
        deserialized.get(0).put("myNewKey", "myNewValue");

        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(deserialized));
    }

}
```

This gives you the following output :

```
[{"1":"xxx","20":"ppp","25":"hhh","myNewKey":"myNewValue"}]
```